# A random variable $Z = f(X, Y)\mod (n+1)$ gives a uniform distribution random varialbes $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let there be a set $S = \{0, 1, 2,....n\}$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables such that their values are chosen independently and randomly from the set.

My curiosity stems from the fact that for a RV $Z = (X+Y)\mod(n+1)$, the distribution for $P(Z) = P(X) = P(Y) = \frac{1}{n+1}$ which I have derived. It also makes intuitive (perhaps illusionary) sense that selecting a $Z$ is equivalent to selecting two numbers $X$ and $X$ randomly, so the selection of $Z$ should also be uniform. I am aware there are some counter-examples but I am not to come up with a satisfactory intuitive reason as to why

> that selecting a $Z$ is equivalent to selecting two numbers $X$ and $X$ randomly, so the selection of $Z$ should also be uniform

does not hold true for any $Z = f(X, Y)\mod n$ for some function $f$. Is it even possible or am I just rambling about math that I do not and cannot understand?

Comment: I do not think you can say *"selecting a $Z$ is equivalent to selecting two numbers $X$ and $Y$ randomly"* as in one case you get one number and in the other two: you cannot derive $X$ and $Y$ from $Z$.  Nor would you hope to get this result in general with something beyond addition mod $n$ or $n+1$, though it will work in a few cases, such as $X$ and $Y$ iid uniform real in $[0,k]$ and addition mod $k$